# Replace all occurences of string in column MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, replace, guid

I am working with a database with a column which consists of data of what I think is a GUID, c92e5daa-ae5b-4d8e-a20d-9c1f660a7081. I have 4 of these which occurs several times and I want to replace then with something more convenient like this:

```
c92e5daa-ae5b-4d8e-a20d-9c1f660a7081 --> String1
c92e5daa-ae5b-4d8e-a20d-9c1f660a7081 --> String2
c92e5daa-ae5b-4d8e-a20d-9c1f660a7081 --> String3
c92e5daa-ae5b-4d8e-a20d-9c1f660a7081 --> String4
```

Now I know that I have a few options. I could run a SQL query with the replace function, but that won't do it since the db is always getting new data.
I've been thinking about replacing them with conditional statements in my program, but I'm not sure about that one either.

Any ideas of what would be the cleanest and best way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

IF you have currently-existing data in your database, I suspect the simplest solution is to run the update using a replace function, to modify your currently existing data, and then:

Perform your string validation and manipulation (in this case, checking its value and modifying it accordingly), in your application layer, to prevent ever inserting these strings in the database in the future. This has the advantage of simplicity.

You could, for instance, construct a dictionary type object and store the strings you want to replace as keys, with the replacement values as values.  Then, when inserting, just check the dictionary for whether a key exists, if so, substitute its value.

Comment: Your first suggestion is probably the best, but unfortunately I don't have control of the insert queries at the application layer. What my application does is exporting a sqlite database as a csv file to import it in a Mysql database so that I can use the data remotely. I'm thinking about making a powershell script that runs the query "UPDATE table SET column="String1" WHERE column="c92e5daa-ae5b-4d8e-a20d-9c1f660a7081" everytime I insert new data. (as anwered by user1403333). I just need to run the script once a day.

Comment: That will certainly work, but I think if your tables grow very large at all, this approach will quickly become terribly inefficient (in terms of overhead)

Comment: Redbeard011010 , your right. I much rater do it to the data I'm inserting which is 4-6 rows once a day. Could I do the UPDATE query with a WHERE clause and replace the GUIDs for a specific date? Because then I could replace all my rows once and from then on only replace the newly added rows onnce a day?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET column="String1" WHERE column="c92e5daa-ae5b-4d8e-a20d-9c1f660a7081"
```

Comment: If the new strings are a competently new type of data, create a new column for them and make the application(s) that write to the table start writing to both columns. Once that's in place, make all readers use the new column and then dispose of the old column (modifying the writers to stop using it as well).

Comment: This is not a complete answer.  Show him how to store "string1" etc in to another table and then how to join the tables.